# Change wp_link_pages to link to another page

Tags: categories

I need a hand please.

I justed started my first website :-)

I am actually using categories and subcategories for my structure. My main categories have a  description, a section with the last articles of the current category (without children articles), and then a list of the subcategories with related articles underneath.

My problem is that I would like the "Next or previous" links underneath the section of my main categories' articles to link to the pages that would use a different layout.

Those links now link to pages that use the same template (in my case : category.php).

I have read that it has something to do with the wp_link_pages parameters (more file) but I don't know how to do that..

Thanks a lot in advance

All the best

Franz

Comment: To be clear, the current page youre working on is [category.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) and you do not want to have next/prev page links to the same template? I would suggest doing a custom template for your main page. And I would start by understanding the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png). Or find a [good web post explaining template hierarchy](https://torquemag.io/2014/12/wordpress-template-hierarchy-explained/).

Comment: What are the next and previous pages supposed to be? What would be different about the template?

Comment: Thanks for the link..I knew about template hierarchy but maybe I am using it in the wrong way..

I do have a file called category-$slug.php.. I use it as a kind of general page to describe that category, display recent or sticky posts, display its sub-categories and its recent or sticky posts.

I have next pages like this : /local/category-slug/page/2/

And this page is using the same file to display the posts.. 

I would like that "page" to be different, more simple ... for instance just a title "All category-Slug articles" and the posts listed simply below..